# My Geo Nodes are gone? Object is there but anything else gone

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

Probably super dumb but I cant find my geometry nodes. If I go into the geo nodes viewer and select the second Node Tree entry I get to the some small objects I distributed around my main object but if I click on the first entry it is completly empty ( I clicked home button to make sure it not just out of sight or something).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first image has GN listed but it is not assigned to selected object. Is it possible GN is used for some another object? What do you see in Modifier panel? Does the GN listed there?

Comment: YES! It was listed in the modifier panel and when I  clicked on "Output Attributes" the Nodes appeared! Thank you